# Double Limit implies Successive Limits

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I know it seems very stupid question, but is it right that:

Suppose $X$ being a complete metric space. Then:
$$\lim_{(m,n)}x_{(m,n)}\quad\text{exists} \quad\Rightarrow\quad \lim_n\lim_m x_{(m,n)}\quad\text{exists}$$
...obviously, the limits agre if so and the converse fails in general.

I'm missing the proof that for large enough fixed $n_0$:
$$x_{(m,n)}\quad(m,n)\text{-cauchy} \quad\Rightarrow\quad x_{(m,n_0)}\quad (m)\text{-cauchy}$$

Thanks in advance! Cheers, Alex.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation, what is $x_{(m,n)}$? is it a sequence with two components?

Comment: yes, i mean a sequence with to indices like $x_{(m,n)}:=\frac{1}{n}\sin(\frac{1}{m})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f(m,n)=(-1)^{m}/n+(-1)^n/m$.
Here $\lim_{(m,n)}f(m,n)$ exists, but neither $\lim_{m}f(m,n)$ nor $\lim_{n}f(m,n)$ exist.

Define $g(m,n)=m/(m+n)-n/(m+n)$.
Here $\lim_{(m,n)}g(m,n)$ not exists, but both $\lim_{m}g(m,n)$ and $\lim_{n}g(m,n)$ exist.

Comment: but I assume we mean $(m,n)\to(\infty,\infty)$?

Comment: I assume $m\in(\mathbb{N},\geq)$
Taking arbitrary sequence of indices is another (much heavier) topic: $\lim_{x\to a}\equiv(\forall x_n\to a)$

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. I was thinking on the behavior I wanted at the point by looking at zero.

Answer (score 0):

Oh just got a counterexample:
$$x_{(m,n)}:=\frac{1}{n}\sin(m)$$
Here, the double limit exists while the successive limits don't.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if $x_{(m,n)}$ is $(m,n)\text{-cauchy}$, then it's also $(m,n)\text{-convergent}$ ( because $X$ complete), and so: $$\exists \lim_{m,n}x_{m,n} \Rightarrow \exists\lim_n\lim_mx_{m,n}\Rightarrow \\ \Rightarrow\exists n_0\in \mathbb N \mid\forall p,q\ge n_0, |x_{p,n_0}-x_{q,n_0}|<\varepsilon, \forall\varepsilon>0.$$
Is that it? I hope so

Edit: this only holds if the successive limits exist, maybe someone knows a condition for that?

Comment: Yeah if it exists then it is clear. Unfortunately, it not necessarily exists (counterexample given below). Hmm, I don't know what kind of condition one would require for it to exist.

Comment: But what you're saying is that you can prove it's $m$-cauchy regardless of the successive limts, correct? This might be difficult :P

Comment: No, you actually cannot!

Comment: Hey, there's a precise condition when this fails and when this holds:

$$x_{(m,n)}\quad(m,n)\text{-cauchy} \quad\Rightarrow\quad x_{(m,n)} \quad(m)\text{-bounded},(n)\text{-bounded}$$

Goin from this, it fails to hold if it is alternating w.r.t. one of the indices.